# SWI-Prolog not labelling more than 9 variables

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I want 10 variables with constraints, but Prolog only labels 9. Here's my code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
colour(Regions) :-
    Regions = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J],
    Regions ins 1..10, 
    all_distinct(Regions),
    labeling([], Regions).

%%% Output:
?-colour(X).
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 8|...] ;   % only 9 variables labelled.
```

**Note:**
It works perfectly fine for `ins 1..9` with 9 variables.

Comment: All the variables are labeled. SWI Prolog just abbreviates long lists (with `...`) when displayed. Instead of `;` or space, try `w` at the first prompt for an answer, and subsequent answers will show fully. The `w` will show the full answer. See [Help: I want the whole answer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html).

Comment: @lurker that should be an answer, not just a comment.